# Error in setting ApplicationLicenseKey in TInAppPurchase in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, delphi-xe6

Based on embarcadero documentations here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Adding_In-App_Payments_to_Your_Mobile_Apps#Configuring_the_Connection_Data_for_Your_In-App_Payment_Service  I tried to assign ApplicationLicenseKey, but I get this error `[DCC Error] MainFrm.pas(413): E2056 String literals may have at most 255 elements`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution the string literal can not exceed 255 chars, so I should break it into small pieces (each one less than 255 chars) and concat them.

like this:

```
  InAppPurchase1.ApplicationLicenseKey := 
'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqP'+
'+hksdEZkVWseD9aQoI5RzaMnj0Ep+VUjXnZmVpVNzAmjdw9tS+'+
'dHh3AcrEuUs9Hw9TtgaSCduBSiVuep5hM/UEnDVOnj8/ND8IJIOPj+'+
'Yezrpbt+9W92LSkN3lNcm3weOz5IW2rUaw0PLLZx13PyLXMpOFe+uJ3aW9hcGl/'+
'bDIMOeaFK9HWAGRTJGmmtfGUWQ0fe85mQXRwyrQncdoKLivHzKykzaR2wNuPBBLXpoHmEtIGGwnUFdAFUE8UqMQVepdtHVW9uNq/9e40lApkuQyoVKzZv31O56DF/'+
'jMkuIwHry+0ZoRrGA3oxeZAUy/iKsTMwz+v8G0qJ8eIDdmtQIDAQAB';
```

p.s. The thing is I just wrote like the sample in the embarcadero site.